# How to treat nested mercurial repository as if it were not a repository but part of parent?

Tags: mercurial

I've got a PHP project that uses composer to pull in packages, and one is an hg repository. The project itself is an hg repository, so I guess the package installed and/or updated by composer is a nested repository.

When composer update is run on the project, if there were changes in the nested repository, I like to push all of those changes up to Bitbucket, as if they were part of the project. By the way, I'm using TortoiseHG, and don't use the terminal for this.

During one of these pushes, TortoiseHG gives errors associated with the nested repository. So I thought that I would just use .hgignore to ignore the .hg folder of the nested repository:

```
vendor/vendor-name/package-name/.hg
```

This has no effect. My attempt to have the contents of the nested repository treated as files of the parent project fail.

If I delete the .hg folder in the nested repository, then the files are treated as files in the parent project, but if I run composer update on the project it barks at me, saying that it can't find the .hg file in the nested repository.

How do I manage this situation? I want to be able to update the package (nested repository), but I also want to have it treated as part of the parent project.

Comment: Have you looked into hg [subrepos](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository)? Make sure you review the Recommendations section as they are considered a "feature of last resort".

Comment: I read through that, and I don't think I would be able to do what I want to do. I just want the parent repo to consider the subrepo as if it was not a subrepo.